# Probability: Game of Cards

Tags: probability

Two cards from 52 card sets were missing. A card from the rest of the cards was selected randomly. What is the probability that it is a spade?

---

I have solved this problem like this,

[image]

So total → $\dfrac{36}{50}$

but the answer given is like→

[image]

Are they correct? And why can't I solve it in the way which I have done?

Comment: Does it make sense to you that removing two cards would increase the chance of getting a spade ?

Answer (score 2):

The two cards missing can be anything, thus it doesn't affect the probability to get a spade, which is still $\frac{1}{4}$. Imagine all but one card was missing, i.e. 51 cards missing, the remaining one has the same probability to be a spade, that if you would select one card among the full set of 52 cards.

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed correct. You only calculated *conditional* probabilities. There remains to apply the *formula of total probabilities* which the recall (adapted to this case) in the first line of the image.